# search the tableview using mvvm

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

I need to search in the tableview.I have tableview and textfield.While clicking on the textfield it must search the tableview.

my model:-

```
     class SearchModel: NSObject {


 var restaurantname :String!


    init?(dictionary :JSONDictionary) {

        guard let name = dictionary["name"] as? String  else {
                return
        }

        self.restaurantname = name

    }



}
```

my viewmodel:-

```
class SearchViewModel: NSObject {


    var datasourceModel:SearchDataSourceModel

    init(withdatasource  newDatasourceModel: SearchDataSourceModel) {
        datasourceModel = newDatasourceModel
    }


    func datafordisplay(atindex indexPath: IndexPath) -> SearchModel{
        return  datasourceModel.dataListArray![indexPath.row]

    }

    func numberOfRowsInSection(section:Int) -> Int {

        return (datasourceModel.dataListArray?.count)!
    }




    func loadData(completion :@escaping (_ isSucess:Bool) -> ()){


        loadFromWebserviceData { (newDataSourceModel) in

            if(newDataSourceModel != nil)
            {




                self.datasourceModel = newDataSourceModel!
                completion(true)

            }
            else{
                completion(false)
            }
        }
    }


    //}
    func loadFromWebserviceData(completion :@escaping (SearchDataSourceModel?) -> ()){

        //with using Alamofire  ..............

        Alamofire.request("http://www.example.com").validate(statusCode: 200..<300).validate(contentType: ["application/json"]).responseJSON{ response in


            switch response.result{

            case .success(let data):
                print("success",data)


                let result = response.result
                if     let wholedata = result.value as? [String:Any]{


                    if  let data = wholedata["data"] as? Array<[String:Any]>{
                        //  print(data["name"] as! String)
                        print(data)
                        print(response)
                        let newDataSource:SearchDataSourceModel = SearchDataSourceModel(array: data)

                        completion(newDataSource)
                        //       }
                    }
                }
                //  case .failure(let data):
                //  print("fail",data)


            case .failure(let encodingError ):
                print(encodingError)


                //  if response.response?.statusCode == 404{


                print(encodingError.localizedDescription)

                completion(nil)

                //   }
            }




        }}
}
```

my datasource model:-

```
class SearchDataSourceModel: NSObject {



    var dataListArray:Array<SearchModel>? = []




    init(array :Array<[String:Any]>?) {
        super.init()
        var newArray:Array<[String:Any]> = []
        if array == nil{

         //   newArray = self.getJsonDataStored44()
        }
        else{
            newArray = array!

        }

        var datalist:Array<SearchModel> = []
        for dict in newArray{

            let model = SearchModel(dictionary: dict)

            datalist.append(model!)
        }
        self.dataListArray = datalist


          }



}
```

my viewcontroller:-

```
class SearchViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate {


    @IBOutlet private weak var tableView: UITableView!
  !
    @IBOutlet weak var txt: UITextField!

    var filteredSearchArray = NSMutableArray()



    private var searchViewModel :SearchViewModel!

    init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?, withViewModel viewModel:SearchViewModel) {

        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)

        searchViewModel  = viewModel
    }



    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }



    var filteredData: [String]!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()




        txt.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(textField:)), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)



        searchViewModel.loadData { (isSuccess) in


            if(isSuccess == true)
            {


                self.tableView .reloadData()


            }
            else{


                }
        }



    }


    @objc private func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {
        if textField.text == "" {
           self .viewDidLoad()
        }else{
            filterContentForSearchText(searchText: textField.text!)
        }
    }



    func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String) {
        filteredSearchArray = NSMutableArray(array:(searchViewModel.datasourceModel.dataListArray?.filter({(ele:AnyObject) -> Bool in
            return (ele as! SearchModel).restaurantname.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
        }))!)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return searchViewModel.numberOfRowsInSection(section: section)
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let identifier = "searchcell"
        var cell: SearchCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? SearchCell

        if cell == nil {
            tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "SearchCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: identifier)
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as?SearchCell
        }


   cell.setsearchData(search: searchViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath))



        return cell
    }


}
```

my tableviewcell:-

```
class SearchCell: UITableViewCell {




  @IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }


    func setsearchData(search:SearchModel)
    {
        self.name.text = search.restaurantname


    }
}
```

This is my code but in the filteredSearchArray always shows as 0 element.

Here the list of names is displaying but clicking on the textfield it doesn't searching and not reloading. How to solve the problem.

The data is not coming  in this code:-

```
 func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String) {
        filteredSearchArray = NSMutableArray(array:(searchViewModel.datasourceModel.dataListArray?.filter({(ele:AnyObject) -> Bool in
            return (ele as! SearchModel).restaurantname.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
        }))!)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: what all changes must do in viewmodel and viewcontroller to get the value

Comment: Could you please show your model class? And how you defined the array?

Comment: @TheTiger i have updated my code .please check.what all changes needed in viewmodel and viewcontroller

Comment: Is data visible initially when you don't search anything? I mean you sure array contains the data?

Comment: @TheTiger initially the data will load in the tableview.

Comment: @TheTiger how to solve the problem.what all changes needed to do in viewmodel and viewcontroller

Comment: @TheTiger initially the data from the api is loading in the tableview but while clicking on the textfield for search here on the search function the data is not coming.I think the search function should write in viewmodel.How to do ?And also after seraching it don't reloading the table.How to solve this issuse

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

First of all one important thing don't use `NSArray`, `NSDictionary` in `swift` use `Array`, `Dictionary` instead.

I have made a change in your model class:

```
class SearchModel: NSObject {
    var restaurantname :String!
    init(dictionary :JSONDictionary) {
        self.restaurantname = dictionary["name"] as? String ?? ""
    }
}
```

Now filter your array like this:

```
filteredSearchArray = searchViewModel.datasourceModel.dataListArray?.filter {$0.restaurantname.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())}
```

And now pass `filteredSearchArray` in `tableView` datasource then reload the table. You can take a `bool` variable `isSearching` to check which array you have to pass in datasource the filtered one the original. Toggle this `isSearching` in `textFieldDidBeginEiditng` and `textFieldDidEndEiditng` method.

I have tested it by below example in my playground:

```
var models: Array<SearchModel> = [SearchModel.init(dictionary: ["name": "Khalsa Dhaba"]), SearchModel.init(dictionary: ["name": "Yo! China"]), SearchModel.init(dictionary: ["name": "Sher-e-punjab"]), SearchModel.init(dictionary: ["name": "Haveli"])]
let result = models.filter {$0.restaurantname.lowercased().contains("o!".lowercased())}
print(result)
```

It works fine! 
Secondly I noticed you're reloading your view by calling `self.viewDidLoad()` method which you should not call ever this calls itself and it is a function of `viewContoller` lifecycle. Call `tableView.reloadData()` instead.

Comment: i have not understand how too implement in my code.where does the filteredSearchArray should give .is in viewcontroller or model.

Comment: `searchViewModel.numberOfRowsInSection(section: section)` and `cell.setsearchData(search: searchViewModel.datafordisplay(atindex: indexPath))`

Comment: You can either defined another function and array in your search model for `filteredArray` or you can just do it in `ViewController`. `if isSearching {use fileteredArray} else the code you have already`

Comment: @ TheTiger  showing an error as :- cannot assign value of type[SearchModel]? to type as NSMutableArray

Comment: Don't use `NSMutableArray` use `Array` only. Defined `filteredSearchArray` same as your original array so that `Array<SearchModel>`

Comment: IS IN THIS WAY:-   var filteredSearchArray = Array<QM_SearchModel>  is in this way,is  filteredSearchArray should declare in the viewcontroller.according to this code showing error as:-   '>' is not postfix unary operation.how to solve

Comment: Tiger here also showing an error as:-property 'self.filteredSerachArray' is not initialized at super.init call .how to solve it

Comment: hOW TO WRITE THE CODE FOR search in viewmodel

Comment: In `SearchViewModel` class take a variable `var isSearching: Bool = false` will false by default, and a `fileteredArray`. Then toggle this bool value in `textField` delegates and update the `fileteredArray`. Then later on `searchViewModel.datafordisplay` method check if `isSearching` is true then fetch data from `fileteredArray`. Got it?

Comment: sorry i not got the answer.According to my viewmodel which i have already uploaded how to do in that